# Elementary OS GUI is deleted

Tags: updates, desktop, gala, repositories, desktop-environment

I did `sudo apt autoremove` on the terminal, and it has removed by elementary desktop.

I tried doing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop`, and the terminal says some unable to find some packages, use `sudo apt update` or try `--fix-missing`.

I tried `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, but it did not work, I also tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: `terminal says some unable to find some packages` Please add the output of `sudo apt install elementary-desktop` to your question, we need to see what those packages are.

Comment: The terminal says this exact error:
`E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: Do you have any PPAs added? Maybe try removing those and then install elementary-desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had timeshit installed on my PC, so I restored my system to a previous snapshot from the command line.

The desktop environment is reinstalled now.